# Given a topological space $X$, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ is defined to be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the discrete topology on $X$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm currently reading from Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* textbook, and one connection I've made while reading is the following: the Borel set over topological space $X$ is defined to be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the discrete topology on $X$.

This seems to me to be a valid conclusion to draw from the textbook, seeing how Rudin motivates the introduction of Borel $\sigma$-algebras. However, being that Rudin doesn't explicitly state such, I was curious whether this was a valid claim?

As far as my background in topology is concerned: I have yet to take a course which focuses solely topology. My only experience with such comes almost entirely from Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* and Folland's *Real Analysis*. If anybody can help answer my question, I would be grateful. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the question. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets of a topological space.

Comment: The $\sigma$-algebra generated by the discrete topology on $X $ is $P(X).$ That's not what the Borel $\sigma$ algebra is at all.

Comment: @DavidLui I have updated the question to fix some of the language I use. But to clarify on here, my thought process is that the largest topology of a topological space (which we know to exist, and is called the discrete topology [as I understand]) is the set which contains all open subsets of a topological space. Thus, we defining the Borel $\sigma$-algebra as being the set generated by all open sets in a topological space, my conclusion is then that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is simple the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the discrete topology.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen It seems I have a misunderstanding on what exactly is a topology: My understanding is that all open sets of a topological space are necessarily contained in a topology (since that is how elements of a topology are denoted). Could you give a more concrete counterexample? Elaborate on your comment.

Comment: @JAG131 You say 'open set' as if that is something that doesn't depend on the topology. But 'what sets are open' is exactly the information a topology contains.

Comment: A topological space ***is*** a set together with a given topology. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra ***is*** the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the given topology. Other possible topologies on that set (the largest topology which happens to be the discrete topology; the smallest topology which happens to be the indiscrete topology; the cofinite topology; the weirdest topology; the blah topology; the snerd topology) are all entirely irrelevant to defining the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the ***given*** topology.

Comment: If you have a misunderstanding on what exactly is a topology, then you should be asking about *that*.

Comment: @JAG131 Say we have the set of real numbers. We could give that many different topologies. The standard topology is the one generated by the open intervals. The discrete topology is the one where every set is open. In each of these cases we get a different Borel sigma algebra corresponding to the topology.

Comment: @LeeMosher I see! That makes a lot more sense. So the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is dependent specifically on which topology is chosen for a topological space? That clears it up. The misunderstanding I was having was that Folland motivates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in a manner that may lead one to believe a topological space has exactly one unique Borel $\sigma$-algebra regardless of the chosen topology. That makes so much more sense, thanks again!

Comment: @JAG131 a topological space has a unique topology by definition and hence a unique Borel algebra. A topological space is a set + a topology. (Just like a group is a set + some operations, or a poset is a set + a partial order relation.)

Comment: @JAG131 (so there are many topologies one could put on a *set*. When you say a topological space, it means you have fixed one.)